# How to approach questions like these where limit and summation both are present together?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm unable to solve the following problem:

$$
\lim_{x → ∞} \left( \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \left( \frac xn \right)^n \right) ^{1/x}
$$

How to approach questions like these where limit and summation both are present together?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Also (might be a bit of knit-picking): what is exactly the question? You've cited only a term. Do we want a "simpler equal term"?

Comment: I am doubtful that there is a general strategy to simplify terms with two limits and a sum (the infinite summation is a limt of the partial sums).

Comment: For this sum, one bit that might simplify it a bit: the tail of the sum is tiny because
$\sum_{n = \lceil 2x \rceil + 1}^{∞} (x/n)^n ≤ \sum_{n = \lceil 2x \rceil + 1}^{∞} (1/2)^n = (1/2)^{\lceil 2x \rceil}$. But the rest looks unhandy and weird.

Comment: Does truncating the sum help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote $\displaystyle S(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)^n$.

We will find the asymptotics of $S(s)$ at $x\to\infty$, using the fact that
$$ \boxed{\,\,S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)^n=x\int_0^1t^{-xt}dt=x\int_0^1e^{-xt\ln t}dt\,\,}$$
Indeed, making the substitution $t=e^{-s}$
$\displaystyle x\int_0^1t^{-xt}dt=x\int_0^\infty e^{-s}e^{sxe^{-s}}ds\tag*{}$

Decomposing the exponent and integrating term by term,

$\displaystyle x\int_0^1e^{-xt\ln t}dt=x\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\big(1+sxe^{-s}+\frac{(sx)^2}{2!}e^{-2s}+\frac{(sx)^3}{3!}e^{-3s}+...\big)ds\tag*{}$

$\displaystyle =x\Gamma(1)+\frac{x^2}{2^2}\frac{\Gamma(2)}{1!}+\frac{x^3}{3^3}\frac{\Gamma(3)}{2!}+...=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)^n\tag*{}=S(x)$

Now we can use the Laplace's method to find the asymptotics at $x\to\infty$.
We notice that $f(x)=t\ln t$ has a minimum on the interval $[0;1]$:
$\displaystyle f'(t)=\ln t+1=0\,\Rightarrow\,t=\frac{1}{e}\tag*{}$

and we can decompose the function near this point into the Taylor series:

$\displaystyle f(t)=f\Big(\frac{1}{e}\Big)+\frac{1}{2}f^{''}\Big(\frac{1}{e}\Big)\Big(t-\frac{1}{e}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{6}f^{'''}\Big(\frac{1}{e}\Big)\Big(t-\frac{1}{e}\Big)^3+...\tag*{}$

Evaluating the derivatives, we get

$\displaystyle f(t)=-\frac{1}{e}+\frac{e}{2}\Big(t-\frac{1}{e}\Big)^2-\frac{e^2}{6}\Big(t-\frac{1}{e}\Big)^3+\frac{e^3}{12}\Big(t-\frac{1}{e}\Big)^4+...\tag*{}$

Denoting $t-\frac{1}{e}=s$ and putting $f(t)$ into the integral

$\displaystyle S(x)=xe^\frac{x}{e}\int_{-1/e}^{1-1/e} e^{-\frac{xe}{2}s^2+\frac{xe^2}{6}s^3-\frac{xe^3}{12}s^4+...}\,ds\tag*{}$

With the accuracy up to exponentially small corrections we can expand integration to $\pm\infty$. Also, at $s\sim\frac{1}{x^{2/5}}\quad e^{-\frac{xe}{2}s^2}\ll1$ , while other terms in the power of the exponet are still very small, for example, $xs^3\sim x^{-1/5}\ll1;\quad xs^4\sim x^{-3/5}\ll1$, etc. This is a heuristic consideration, but the accurate analysis is straightforward and confirms this approach.
Therefore, we are allowed to expand the exponent into the series. Integrating term by term, we get the desired asymptotics:

$\displaystyle S(x)= xe^\frac{x}{e}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{xe}{2}s^2}\Big(1+\frac{xe^2}{6}s^3-\frac{xe^3}{12}s^4+\frac{x^2e^4}{72}s^6+...\Big)ds\tag*{}$

Integration is straightforward. Grouping the terms,

$\displaystyle \boxed{\,\,S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)^n=e^\frac{x}{e}\sqrt\frac{2\pi x}{e}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{24}\frac{e}{x}+O\Big(\frac{1}{x^2}\Big)\bigg)\,\,\text{at}\,\,x \to\infty\,\,}\tag*{}$

The desired limit is now evident:
$$\boxed{\,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(S(x)\Big)^\frac{1}{x}=e^\frac{1}{e}\,\,}$$

Comment: This approach and solution are more than elegant

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, thank you!